# Vagrant boxes poweroff but still running

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm problem with my Vagrant boxes. I had a number of boxes in operation, opened my Vagrantfile to add a new box config. Then when I ran `vagrant up new_box`, I was told that it could not boot and was subsequently placed in `poweroff` state. Now ALL my boxes are in `poweroff` state when I check `vagrant status`. The apps running on these boxes are still running though, but I can't ssh into them. I also cannot run `vagrant halt`, nothing seems to happen. When I run `vagrant up` port collisions occur.

In short, my Vagrant boxes are running (sort of), but they aren't really?

**EDIT**

I have tried destroying a box (rather than just halting) and then running `vagrant up` again, but the port is still occupied when I try to bring the box back up again... However, when I check `netstat` the host ports are not listed as in use by any application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by an update of VirtualBox performed by the server admin (without me knowing). Also, a kernel update was being performed.